# Layout da caixa de comentários quebrada na eleição de moderadores

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, layout

Notei que o layout da caixa de comentários está ligeiramente quebrado na eleição de moderadores, nada que impeça o uso, mas está sobrepondo o link de ajuda e o botão de comentar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aconteceu no Chrome 69 e no Edge, não testei nos outros navegadores.
Nas perguntas do site o layout está correto

Comment: Toda eleição sempre tem um BUG visual/UI, já é tradição hehehe xD

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento faz parte do processo? :)

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar isso. Eu adicionarei isso à nossa fila de erros.

Answer (score 2):

A equipe de desenvolvedores olhou para isso e eles não conseguiram reproduzir o erro. Vou marcar isso como resolvido. Se surgir novamente, por favor me avise.